# Return lookup results with condition on single field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, lookup

I have following schema:

```
  User Schema: 
   { userId:"Id1",name:"abc"}, { userId:"Id2",name:"efg"}, { userId:"Id3",name:"lmn"}, { userId:"Id4",name:"xyz"}

  Image Schema:
   { userId:"Id1",imageUrl:"url1",isFlaged:true},{ userId:"Id1",imageUrl:"url2",isFlaged:false},{ userId:"Id1",imageUrl:"url3",isFlaged:false},
   { userId:"Id2",imageUrl:"url4",isFlaged:true},{ userId:"Id2",imageUrl:"url5",isFlaged:false},
   { userId:"Id3",imageUrl:"url6",isFlaged:false},{ userId:"Id3",imageUrl:"url7",isFlaged:false},
   { userId:"Id4",imageUrl:"url8",isFlaged:false},{ userId:"Id4",imageUrl:"url9",isFlaged:false},
```

I want to get all the userIds that have no flagged images, i.e., `isFlaged` is 'false' for all it's images ( in other words, user have no images that has `isFlaged` set true)

Like the result for above data should return  `users with userIds Id3 and Id4` as all their images have `isFlaged` as false, and none true

I have tried below approaches

```
db.users.aggregate([
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'images',
            let: {userID: '$userId'},
            pipeline: [
              {
                $match: {
                  $expr: {
                    $and: [{$eq: ['$userId','$$userID']},
                    // tried this too {$ne: ['$isFlaged',false]}],
                  },
                },
              },
              {
                $project: {
                  _id: 0,
                  imageUrl: 1,
                  isFlaged:1,
                }
              },
            ],
            as: 'image',
          },
        },
        {
            $match:{
              '$image.isFlaged':{
                 $nin:[true]  // or using {$not:{$all:[false]}}
               } 
            }
        },
        {
          $limit: 10
        },
        {
          $project: {
            userId: 1,
            image: '$image'
          },
        }
      ]);
```

I am not good with aggregations. I just tried experimenting with queries, yet nothing seemed to work. So can anyone please tell me how do you do this? Or any useful links would be helpful too. I am not sure what query or method to use, as Idk much about monogodb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to correct `$match` stage condition

- `"image.isFlaged"` should not true and `image` not equal to empty

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "images",
      let: { userId: "$userId" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: { $eq: ["$$userId", "$userId"] } }
          }
        },
        { $project: { _id: 0, imageUrl: 1, isFlaged: 1 } }
      ],
      as: "image"
    }
  },
  { $match: { image: { $ne: [] }, "image.isFlaged": { $ne: true } } },
  { $limit: 10 },
  {
    $project: {
      userId: 1,
      image: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AQezEdaLzi4)

Comment: I had a doubt, the condition isFlaged:false in lookup match, only matches those documents with isFlaged field set as false ryt? I mean it will ignore the document with isflaged as true ? what does isFlaged: false in lookup match do?

Comment: i just realised it was incorrect, i have just updated answer.

Comment: Yes it works... also if suppose i want to return only flagged images of all users and for those who have none flagged image it should return null.. how would i do that then? Like for this case the result should be like... [ {userId: 'Id1', imageUrl: 'url1'} , {userId: 'Id2', imageUrl: 'url4' } , { userId: 'Id3', imageUrl: null} , { userId: 'Id4' , imageUrl: null} ]

Comment: what is there are 2 flaged images, how to decide which one select in result `{userId: 'Id1', imageUrl: 'url1'}`

Comment: No for now only one is flagged... I have different collection where there is similar thing but only one of it is true, rest all is false. so consider only one is flagged and rest not for now..

Comment: see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eL3FW1JtwCy)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232276/discussion-between-ksk-and-turivishal).

Comment: I had similar issues too, it helped . Tq :)